# Show That The Perimeter Of The Evolute Of The Ellipse Is $4(\frac{ a^2}{b} - \frac{b^2}{a})$.

Tags: curvature

According to the question we have to find the perimeter of evolute of an ellipse.

For an ellipse $\dfrac{x^2}{a^2} + \dfrac{y^2}{b^2} = 1$, the equation of its evolute is

$$(ax)^\frac{2}{3}+(by)^\frac{2}{3} = (a^2 - b^2)^\frac{2}{3}$$

To get the points of intersection of Ellipse and evolute we have to solve these two Equations. How can we solve? Plus, Can you help me to find whole sum?

Comment: The question in the title doesn't fit the question in your text (perimeter vs. intersection points)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming $a>b$,

\begin{align*}
  \mathbf{r} &=
  \begin{pmatrix}
    \frac{a^2-b^2}{a} \cos^3 t \\
    \frac{b^2-a^2}{b} \sin^3 t
  \end{pmatrix} \\
  \dot{\mathbf{r}} &=
  \begin{pmatrix}
    -\frac{3(a^2-b^2)}{a} \cos^2 t \sin t \\
     \frac{3(b^2-a^2)}{b} \sin^2 t \cos t
  \end{pmatrix} \\
  \frac{ds}{dt} &= \frac{3(a^2-b^2)}{ab} |\sin t \cos t|
  \sqrt{a^2 \sin^2 t+b^2 \cos^2 t} \\
  P &= \frac{3(a^2-b^2)}{ab}
  \int_{0}^{2\pi} |\sin t \cos t| \sqrt{a^2 \sin^2 t+b^2 \cos^2 t \,} \; dt \\
  &= \frac{12(a^2-b^2)}{ab} \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}
  \sin t \cos t \sqrt{a^2 \sin^2 t+b^2 \cos^2 t\,} \; dt \\
  &= \frac{12(a^2-b^2)}{ab} \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}
  \frac{\sin 2t}{2} \sqrt{\frac{a^2+b^2}{2}-\frac{a^2-b^2}{2}\cos 2t \,} \; dt \\
  &= \frac{12(a^2-b^2)}{ab} \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}
  \sqrt{\frac{a^2+b^2}{2}-\frac{a^2-b^2}{2}\cos 2t \,} \; d(-\cos 2t) \\
  &= \frac{12(a^2-b^2)}{ab}
  \left[
    \frac{1}{3(a^2-b^2)}
    \left(
      \frac{a^2+b^2}{2}-\frac{a^2-b^2}{2} \cos 2t
    \right)^{3/2}
  \right]_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \\
  &= \frac{4(a^3-b^3)}{ab}
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

solving the ellipse equation for $$y^2$$ we get $$y^2=b^2-\frac{b^2x^2}{a^2}$$ and the evolute as $$b^2y^2=((a^2-b^2)^{2/3}-(ax)^{2/3})^3$$ then you can eliminate $$y^2$$